# Possible to use a singleton with a non-default constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, singleton, parameter-passing

This is a slight variance of this question: [Possible to use a singleton with a non-default constructor in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885972/possible-to-use-a-singleton-with-a-non-default-constructor-in-c)

I have a class that takes parameters for it's constructor. I would like to make this singleton such that the parameters are taken upon initialising the singleton and thus would not need to be passed in each time the instance is retrieved.

My solution (which is not elegant) for this is to have a `CreateInstance()` static method that takes the parameters and constructs the singleton instance. I would then have another static method `GetInstance()` which would be parameterless to obtain the singleton instance. In code, I would then need to ensure the logic calls `CreateInstance` before any calls to GetInstance. However, I cannot enforce this at compile time. I can, however, check at runtime by throwing an exception in `GetInstance` if it is called before `CreateInstance`.

Is there anyway I can achieve this behaviour with compile time enforcement? Or at the very least, is there a better way of doing the same thing?

Comment: @user691226 could you should some code for how you've done this already, I may have some pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do it at compile time, because that would be like asking the compiler "can you prove that code X is never executed before code Y is executed, in the presence of multiple threads?". It cannot be done.

As for the runtime behavior of your design, I think this is as good as it can ever be.

You can make it slightly better by exposing a `Func<SingletonType>` property in your singleton class. When someone asks for the singleton instance and the instance has not already been created, your class would call this "factory method" to construct the singleton. If the factory method is `null`, then you either throw an exception or (if applicable) construct using some default parameters.

What this does is essentially defer the construction of the singleton until it's actually needed for the first time, so it's *some* improvement. But the underlying principle is the same.

**Update:**

As `LukeH` points out, this is pretty much what `Lazy<T>` does (.NET 4 only). If possible, use that one instead of writing your own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I was hoping that I might have missed a completely different way of achieving the same behaviour that gives me compile time checking.

Comment: You've described pretty much how `Lazy<T>` works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx

Comment: @LukeH: Thanks for the tip, I 've never used that one so far.

Answer (score 1):

In a classic singleton, the **real magic** happens in `static readonly` which creates the instance as soon as it is used:

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private static readonly _instance = new MySingleton();

    private MySingleton() {}

    public static MySingleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

}
```

If you have parameters to pass to constructor, you have to implement locking yourself (note the double `if` sandwitching the `lock`):

```
public class MySingletonWithConstructor
{
    private static _instance;
    private static object _lock = new Object();

    private MySingletonWithConstructor(string myArg) 
    {
        // ... do whatever necessary
    }

    public static MySingletonWithConstructor Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance==null)
            {
                lock(_lock)
                {
                    if(_instance==null) // double if to prevent race condition
                    {
                        _instance = new MySingletonWithConstructor("Something");
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 Nice... I never would have thought of that double `if` construct, and it took me about a minute to understand it. Simple and effective.

Comment: this is a totally useless construct because if the singleton instance getter always passes "Something" ( or some other internally defined value ) then `myArg` isn't functioning as a parameter - at least not as far as consumers are concerned - so effectively this class still has a parameterless constructor

Answer (score 0):

You could just have `GetInstance()` call the `CreateInstance()` method if the singleton object doesn't exist already.

Comment: You can't do this because GetInstance doesn't have the parameters that CreateInstance needs.

Comment: Can you determine what the would need to be

Answer (score 0):

I would do it similar to this. You may have to add locks or other things to ensure:

```
 public class ClassA {     
    private static ClassA instance;

    private int param;

    private ClassA(int param) {
       this.param = param;
    }

    public static ClassA getInstance() {
       if (instance == null) {
          throw new CustomException("Not yet initialised");
       } else {
          return instance;
       }
    }

    public static void createInstance(int param) {
       if (instance == null) {
          instance = new ClassA(param);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the code I already have. Unfortunately the question was whether I can change the runtime enforcement of this behaviour to compile time behaviour. But it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your question. But no, you can't. I think this is more or less the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `GetInstance()` method, why dont you just call CreateInstance if your value is null, then you have lazy initialisation..

Comment: Because he needs to pass arguments to the `CreateInstance` function. This doesn't provide a solution to the question that was asked.

Comment: Where is he getting these magical arguments from if they are not passed into GetInstance, since none are passed into GetInstance i assumed they would be known at this point..

Comment: The question already addresses this: *"My solution (which is not elegant) for this is to have a CreateInstance() static method that takes the parameters and constructs the singleton instance. I would then have another static method GetInstance() which would be parameterless to obtain the singleton instance."*

Answer (score 0):

Use CreateInstance() to be the loader of a `Lazy<T>` and have GetInstance return the Lazy.Value (you might want to create a static readonly field that is set to = thelazy.Value to ensure a single entry into CreateInstance())